# Выбрать из sqlite строку, где столбец совпадает с числом в списке. Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, параметры

Есть список с числами, допустим - [35, 36, 37]
Задача найти совпадение одного числа из списка со столбцом в строках базы данных

Коротко что я хочу сделать, описывая в псевдокоде:

```
a = [33, 34 ,35]

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE age = a;
```

Comment: а что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: `age in (33, 34 ,35)`, `age between 33 and 35` (хотя такого в `sqlite` может и нет)

Comment: @MaxU Выбрать из sqlite строку, где столбец совпадает с числом в списке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все достаточно тривиально - сначала сформируйте параметризированный запрос, потом выполните его, передав список значений как параметры:

```
values = [33, 34, 35, 50]

qry = """SELECT * FROM Users WHERE age IN ({})""".format(",".join("?" * len(values)))

cursor.execute(qry, values)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Пример сгенерированного запроса для списка, сосотоящего из четырех элементов:

```
In [117]: values = [33, 34, 35, 50]
     ...:
     ...: qry = """SELECT * FROM Users WHERE age IN ({})""".format(",".join("?" * len(values)))


In [118]: qry
Out[118]: 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE age IN (?,?,?,?)'
```